# angularjs data-binding not working after i put a controller in body tag

Tags: angularjs

im new and still learning about angularjs, seems i encountered my first problem here. angular data binding is working good until i put the `ng-controller="dataCtrl"`in my body tag.  what seems to be the problem i think i've done the right thing, here the codes i did.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="musicApp">
  <head> 

  <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <title> AMBOT HAIM! </title>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="dataCtrl">

   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search"></input>

   <h5> you input : </h5> {{ search }} 

  </body>

</html>
```

my script code :

```
var app = angular.module("musicApp",[]);


app.Controller("dataCtrl",["$scope", function(){

      $scope.data = [
      {
        firstname: "arnold",
        midname: "mike",
        lastname: "sukina",
      },

       {
        firstname: "bryant",
        midname: "milagro",
        lastname: "simba",
      }]   

}]);
```

Comment: Try this when you declare the controller: `app.Controller("dataCtrl",["$scope", function($scope){`

Comment: same problem sir. if i will not put the ng-controller the data binding will work but if there a controller it wont work anymore

Comment: what is a problem you are facing? You wrote the perfect code.

Comment: What data binding you are talking about. Is it `search` or you want to bind the `$scope.data`. Can't get your problem clearly.

Comment: thx for the concern sir. hehe the problem is as what hdkhardik said all data is wrote perfectly put the brower will display the {{search}} code instead of binding it hehe

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("musicApp",[]);


app.controller("dataCtrl",function($scope){

      $scope.data = [
      {
        firstname: "arnold",
        midname: "mike",
        lastname: "sukina",
      },

       {
        firstname: "bryant",
        midname: "milagro",
        lastname: "simba",
      }]   

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="musicApp">
  <head> 

  <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <title> AMBOT HAIM! </title>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="dataCtrl">

   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search"></input>

   <h5> you input : </h5> {{ search }} 

  </body>

</html>
```

The controller should be in lower case `controller` and the `$scope` should be defined within the function params. Check the above snippet, your code is working fine.

Comment: sir the same problem occur. in my index.html am i doing all right? the links?

Comment: @jamesmanagbanag i have changed the code and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're using ng-model to link the form to the value `search`, however you don't have a `search` value in scope.

Add the `search` value in the scope with:

```
app.Controller("dataCtrl",["$scope", function(){

      $scope.search = "YourValues";

      $scope.data = [
      {
        firstname: "arnold",
        midname: "mike",
        lastname: "sukina",
      },

       {
        firstname: "bryant",
        midname: "milagro",
        lastname: "simba",
      }]   

}]);
```

The ng-model will then link the value from the input to the `$scope.search` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller construction function is missing the `$scope` argument.

```
//DO this
app.Controller("dataCtrl",["$scope", function($scope){
//NOT this
//app.Controller("dataCtrl",["$scope", function(){

      $scope.search = "YourValues";

      $scope.data = [
      {
        firstname: "arnold",
        midname: "mike",
        lastname: "sukina",
      },
```

Comment: i did what you said sir but seems the problems is still there. the browser still output {{search}} code instead of binding it :3

Answer (score 0):

User lowercase for `controller` and `$scope` has to be imported as a function argument. See below:

```
app.controller("dataCtrl",function($scope){
...
});
```

Just replace your line of code with this and don't forget to remove `]` on the last line as well and it should work.